# Replace and delete column values in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains user id and course id. It was decided that some of the courses are actually duplicates and I need to get rid of them. So, this means I have to replace one of the course ids with the other but make sure there are no duplicates.

Here is an example:

```
UserID    CourseID
------    --------
1         1
1         2
1         3
1         4
2         1
2         2
```

They decided course ids 1 and 3 are the same, so need to get rid of 1 and replace with 3 and end up with:

```
UserID    CourseID
------    --------
1         2
1         3
1         4
2         3
2         2
```

So, for user ID 2 is just an update of course id but for user id 1 it is an update and a delete. there is unique constraints in this table for course id so can't update all 1s to 3 and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by deleting those that would make duplicates:

```
delete uc1
from UserCourse uc1
inner join UserCourse uc3 on uc3.UserId = uc1.UserId
where uc1.CourseId = 1 and uc3.CourseId = 3
```

Then, just do the update:

```
update UserCourse set CourseId = 3 where CourseId = 1
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it prevents duplicates from ever entering into the table. Just feels clean. As a total side note, in the first query you could use `delete uc1` to reduce the number of records that have to be updated in the second query. Depending on the size of the table, this could save a little time, but would most likely be irrelevant as this sounds like a "one-off" solution.

Comment: @NathanM.- thanks for the kind words, but you're wrong about the delete uc1 bit. By deleting the 3's tat would make duplicates as I do, you reduce the 3's that need updating. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: My comment was also paired with my edit. I suggested an edit to flip the values in the second update to meet the OP's specs of "so need to get rid of 1 and replace with 3". You're current query gets rid of 3 and replaces them with 1. Unless I am misunderstanding OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two stages... first update.

```
update table 
set CourseID = 3 
where CourseID = 1
```

Then delete the dupes

```
with cte as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by UserID, CourseID order by CourseID) RN
)


select * from cte where RN <> 1
--the below command will delete what is returned from the select
--delete from cte 
--where RN <> 1
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this. The unique constraint (combination of user id and course id) would prevent the update.

Comment: Can you provide the DDL on what the constraint is?